# Make SQL query select another result if first select doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a query always return a result.
Using

```
SELECT art_price, art_header FROM 'signs' WHERE art_number=113
```

and if 113 doesn't exist I want the query to do

```
SELECT art_price, art_header FROM 'signs' WHERE art_number=111
```

I've tried my best with IFNULL and COALESCE and CASE but doesn't get it to work.

How am I supposed to do?

Seems like my php is messing up what @Felix Pemittan solved for me

```html
<?php
include 'dbc.php';
$query = "SELECT 
    art_price, art_header, art_pic, art_row1, art_row2, art_row3, art_row4  
FROM `signs`
WHERE art_number = ?

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    art_price, art_header, art_pic, art_row1, art_row2, art_row3, art_row4 
FROM `signs`
WHERE 
    art_number = 111
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM `signs`
        WHERE art_number = ?
    )";


if($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['art_number']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($rowPrice, $rowHeader, $rowPic, $rowArt1, $rowArt2, $rowArt3, $rowArt4);


    while($stmt->fetch()){
        ?>
```

Comment: These two sql always give you one record or none?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT art_price, art_header FROM 'signs' WHERE  (art_number=113 or (art_number=111 and 
(SELECT art_price, art_header FROM 'signs' WHERE art_number=113) is  null))
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''signs' WHERE art_number = 113 UNION ALL SELECT art_price, art_header F' at line 3

Answer (score 1):

Did you want this?

```
SELECT art_price, art_header
FROM `signs`
WHERE art_number in (113, 111)
ORDER BY art_number DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two queries using `UNION ALL` and then add a `NOT EXISTS` clause to the second query:

```
SELECT 
    art_price, art_header 
FROM `signs`
WHERE art_number = 113

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    art_price, art_header 
FROM `signs`
WHERE 
    art_number = 111
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM `signs`
        WHERE art_number = 113
    )
```

Comment: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''signs' WHERE art_number = 113 UNION ALL SELECT art_price, art_header F' at line 3

Comment: @PetrusAlli Are you sure you copied it right? I don't see any error with my query.

Comment: 'signs' should not be 'enclosed' in apostrophes, then it's interpreted as a string and not a table name. I can't believe all the answers missed this...

Comment: @ToVine Are you sure? I believe `''` is the way to escape table names, or am I missing something?

Comment: @ToVine Welp, you're right. It should be enclose ind `"` or `\``.

Comment: @PetrusAlli answer updated thans to ToVine's comment.

Comment: Ah it worked, but my php didn't work as well as I hoped with it sadly...

Answer (score 0):

**Query:**

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM 'signs' WHERE art_number=113) 
    SELECT art_price, art_header FROM 'signs' WHERE art_number=113 
ELSE 
    SELECT art_price, art_header FROM 'signs' WHERE art_number=111
```